# Every one-element subset of a metric space is closed

Tags: real-analysis

In Shilov's book, "  Elementary Real and Complex Analysis", there is the theorem: If $M$ is a complete metric space consisting of only countably many points, then $M$ has an isolated point.

In his proof, he stated: Every one-element subset of $M$ is closed. But he did not prove this statement.

I have 2 queries:$\;1$.$\;$Can someone please prove this statement.$\;2$.$\;$Is $M$ a Hausdorff space ?

Wikidot

$\;\;\;\;\;$http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-closedness-of-finite-sets-in-a-metric-space

proves singleton subsets of $M$ are closed as follows:

A set $S\subseteq M$ is said to be open in $M$ if $S=\text{int}(S)$ and $S$ is said to be closed if $M{\setminus}S$ is open.

**Lemma 1:**

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space. Then for each $x\in M$ the singleton set $\{x\}$ is closed in $M$.

**Proof:**

Let $x\in M$ and consider the singleton set $\{x\}$.

The complement of $\{x\}$ is $S{\setminus}\{x\}$ which we want to prove is an open set.

Let $y\in M{\setminus}\{x\}$.

Then there exists a distance $d(x,y) > 0$ between the points $y$ and $x$ with respect to the metric $d$.

Let $r=d(x,y)/2$.

Then the open ball centered at $y$ with radius $r$ is:

$$B(y,r)=\{z\in M:d(y,z) < r = d(x,y)/2\}$$

Then we have that the open ball $B(y,r)$ is fully contained in $M{\setminus}\{x\}$.

Hence $y\in \text{int}(M{\setminus}\{x\}$, so $\text{int}(M{\setminus}\{x\})=M{\setminus}\{x\}$.

Thus $M{\setminus}\{x\}$ is an open set, so the singleton set $\{x\}$ is closed. ◼

My query is:

A point $y\in M{\setminus}\{x\}$ can be an isolated point of $M$, hence, for some $r' > 0$, the open ball
$$B(y,r')=\{z\in M:d(y,z) < r'\}$$
contains $y$ only and no other points of $M$, hence no other points of $M{\setminus}\{x\}$.

Therefore $y$ is not an interior point of $M{\setminus}\{x\}$ which means $M{\setminus}\{x\}$ is not open.

Comment: Hint: Two distinct points whose distance apart is $w$ can be separated by open balls of radius $w/2$.

Comment: Now see if you can answer your own question (or at least show an attempt).

Comment: My proof is constructive. The countable points in M can be represented by the rationals. Due to keyboard limitation, I write Xc as the complement of { x } in M. Let y be a point in Xc. Both y and x are represented by rational numbers and there is an open ball of rationals separating y and x. Therefore y is an interior point of Xc which implies Xc is an open set and { x } is closed. But my " proof " has a flaw because Q is not a complete metric space. Wikidot has a proof which uses your method of radius w/2 but to me Wiki's proof requires a leap of faith.

Comment: What's the "leap of faith"? What don't you understand? Also, you should edit your post to include your above attempt. Work should be shown in the main post, not just in a comment.

Comment: Also, if there's a Wiki proof you have issues with, edit your post to include a link.

Comment: Wikidot's link is:http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-closedness-of-finite-sets-in-a-metric-space

Comment: I have edited the main post to reply your comments

Comment: Sorry, something is wrong because mathstackexchange did not post my edit entirely. Unable to proceed.

Comment: I think I've repaired your edit. Please check to make sure it matches the edit you intended.

Comment: My edit fixes r ' = d( y, x ) = distance between  y and x. A point y∈M∖{x} can be an isolated point of M such that  r ' = d( y, x ), the open ball

B(y,r′)={z∈M:d(y,z)< r′ }  with r ' = d( y, x ) contains y only and no other points of M, hence no other points of M∖{x}. Therefore, y is not an interior point of M∖{x}  which means M∖{x} is not open. I think the proof needs to make use of the condition that M is a complete metric space.

Comment: After all these discussions, your proof and Wikidot's proof is correct because by definition, M∖{x}  excludes x and y is always an interior point of M∖{x}